# Performance implications of FittedBox?

Tags: flutter

Often times I will design widgets inside of a `SizedBox` so I can tune in font size and padding to achieve the exact look.

Then wherever I use one of these `SizedBox` widgets, I wrap them in a FittedBox so they scale automatically; it's like magic.

I'm wondering if this has any performance implications, as compared to widgets where I specify font size manually?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry too much about performance

Flutter is designed to use simple algorithms to achieve 60 fps

1 pass layout composition O(n)

Separated layout and painting

Children tell the parent to invalidate the subtrees

etc.

https://youtu.be/VUiVkDpikDI?t=906

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUfXWzp0-DU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkyY9WCGMi0

I cannot say the all the performance implications but it shouldnt matter.